# Type Mismatch Error without showing error line

Tags: excel, vba

My code was working yesterday but today the below shows a type mismatch error for some reason. The code hides certain rows based on criteria. Kindly help. I do not have any experience in VBA.

`

```
Sub HURows()
    BeginRow = 5
    EndRow = 120
    ChkCol = 2
    For Rowcnt = BeginRow To EndRow
        If Cells(Rowcnt, ChkCol).Value = 1 Then
            Cells(Rowcnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Cells(Rowcnt, 5).Value <> "NA" Then
            Cells(Rowcnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Else
                Cells(Rowcnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next Rowcnt
End Sub`
```

Type Mismatch Error

Comment: A type mismatch can occur in the line `Cells(Rowcnt, 5).Value <> "NA"` if the result of a formula is for example #ERROR. Please click on Debug when the message box with the error appears then the line with the error will be highlighted in yellow.

Comment: Do some cells in col 5 contain actual #N/A errors? If so use IsError rather than compare to a string

Answer (score -1):

As Storax says a cell with a #DIV/0 or something similar (not a number) cannot be evaluated as = 1.  Perhaps this will help you out?

```
Sub HURows()
BeginRow = 5
EndRow = 120
ChkCol = 2
For rowcnt = BeginRow To EndRow
    If IsNumeric(Cells(rowcnt, ChkCol).Value) Then
        If Cells(rowcnt, ChkCol).Value = 1 Then
            Cells(rowcnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    ElseIf Cells(rowcnt, 5).Value <> "NA" Then
        Cells(rowcnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            Cells(rowcnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next rowcnt
End Sub
```